# Android Video Splash Screen or Animating Pictures (Fade)

Tags: android, splash-screen, viewpagerindicator

How to create a splash screen - **video clip**. Just like this one. 
I'm trying to make this welcome screen.

It will **always loop, and pause when one of the buttons is click**.
And as it plays the viewPager with circleIndicator swipes it's own.

[image]

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add videoview in your xml as:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center">

       <VideoView
           android:id="@+id/video_app_intro"
           android:layout_width="200.0dip"
           android:layout_height="200.0dip"
           android:layerType="none" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. in your activity.java file add:

   ```
   private boolean videoCompleted = false;
   // path of video in assets folder
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder().append("android.resource://").append(getPackageName()).append("/").append(R.raw.splash);

       videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(stringBuilder.toString()));
       videoView.start();

   videoView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().
   getColor(android.R.color.white));
   videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
   videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
           //wait for 3 seconds
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(3000);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }).start();
           videoCompleted = true;
           if (videoCompleted) {
               goToNextScreen();
           }
           return false;
       }
   });

   videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
           videoCompleted = true;
           if (videoCompleted) {
               goToNextScreen();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

*** you should use a view switcher for video in splash screen, with video and image, for the case when video is not supported.

Comment: Sir I'm having a problem with my video. It can't be played. Frame width 348 x 480 (Height).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `MediaPlayer` with `VideoView` you can start your Activity in `OnCompletionListener`.It start your next activity when the video playback finish.

```
mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try {

          //intent for start new activity

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```